# Reading variable from multi line string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have multiline string in javascript. I have input element the value of which is set to, value fetched from file.

What I am not able to do is to set the value of this input element to value of this variable.

```
let port="";
let xmlData = fs.readFileSync(xmlFileRW,function(err,data){port=data;});

let xmlFileData = `
    <form> 
    <tr>
      <th class="hostid-th-padding">
        <b>PORT</b>
      </th>
      <td class="hostid-td-padding">
        <input id="port" type="text" size="7" value=""+port+"" onkeypress="buttonEnable()"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: `${port}` - use correct template literal syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let port="";
let xmlData = fs.readFileSync(xmlFileRW,function(err,data){port=data;});

let xmlFileData = `
    <form> 
    <tr>
      <th class="hostid-th-padding">
        <b>${port}</b>
      </th>
      <td class="hostid-td-padding">
        <input id="port" type="text" size="7" value="${port}" onkeypress="buttonEnable()"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
`
```

Comment: Hi VLAZ, it works but if the file doesn't exist at all then port value is empty, I see in the input box  "onkeypress="buttonEnable()"

Comment: @karansys `port = data || ""` to set a default value of an empty string.